# Neo4j - no properties for successfully created nodes from CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

My CYPHER Query

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///honours.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Person {Name: row.Name, Award: row.Award});
```

CSV
Name,   Award
Vera Lynn,  Companion of Honour
etc , etc

RESULT
Added 1149 labels, created 1149 nodes, set 2298 properties, statement executed in 0 ms.

Yet despite what it say it says 'no properties' when I click on nodes which are displayed with IDs only - how do I get properties??

Comment: Are you sure about that? The expected number of properties set in the RESULT looks correct. What query are you using to inspect nodes and determine what properties are present?

Comment: yeah, if you're using the browser front end, the properties can sometimes disappear "below the fold"... switch to "Rows" or click the node and click the drop-down arrow in the bottom right of the view window.

Comment: Clicked on Person label in Database Info menu:
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25

Nodes display but with id numbers - no option to change.

It also says 'no properties' in the footer when I click on a node and in Row view it shows (empty) entries.

There's no drop-down arrow showing.

Answer (score 0):

When you've tried some imports before, don't forget to remove the previous data before creating new nodes, or there's always the chance of getting older data when sampling the graph.

With

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE exists(n.Name)
RETURN count(n)
```

you can check that you do have `Person` nodes with properties.

And by executing

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WITH size(keys(n)) AS propCount
RETURN propCount, count(propCount) AS nodeCount
ORDER BY nodeCount DESC;
```

you can see the distribution of the number of properties on existing nodes.

You can also check that the CSV file is correctly read with

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///honours.csv" AS row
RETURN row.Name, row.Award
LIMIT 10
```

To delete all `Person` nodes and start fresh, just execute

```
MATCH (n:Person)
DETACH DELETE n
```